# RAID0 Local SSD on Google Container Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to use Local SSD for one of my applications, however the data is > 350GB, so I would need to use 2 of them.

[gce auto mounts](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/local-ssd) and formats the SSDs into `/mnt/disks/ssdx`, but is there any way I could get the VM to RAID0 the SSDs before mounting?

Would editing the Startup script in a new instance template be the right place for this?

PS: I'm very new to GCE but fairly competent with Linux.

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd) is a GCE article on setting up RAID disks.. May be of some use..

Comment: That article is for Google *Compute* Engine. I am interested on how to do it in Google *Container* Engine, which is basically their hosted Kubernetes offering. I do not want to setup things by hand each time a node comes up.